# Julia async block: couldn't get any result with command prompt

Tags: asynchronous, command-line, command-prompt, julia

I'm working with Julia, my IDE is Juno and the system is Linux.

Here is my script:

```
#test.jl
function testShow(msg)
  println(msg)
end

#@async begin      # 1
  testShow("aaa")
#end               # 2

println("bbb")
```

If I run it in Juno, I can get the result below:

```
aaa
bbb
```

If I remove the comment #1 and #2, meaning that `testShow("aaa")` is in a `async` block and run it in Juno, I can get another result below:

```
bbb
aaa
```

Now, I need to run it with command line. So I open a terminal and type the command below:

```
julia /home/myname/Julia/test.jl
```

if #1 and #2 are commented, I can get a result as expected:

```
aaa
bbb
```

However, if I remove the two comments, I will get such a result:

```
bbb
```

Why? Codes in `@async` block can't be executed with command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make wait for the `@async` task to finish, you're not seeing the output on the commandline because the program is exiting before the task is done.  One way to do this is to capture the task returned by `@async` and wait on the task before exiting your program.

```julia
function testShow(msg)
    println(msg)
end

t = @async begin
    testShow("aaa")
end

println("bbb")
wait(t)
```